# check whether an activemq subscriber is subscribed to a topic or not?

Tags: java, activemq-classic, disconnect

I am working on a code in which there are 3 subscribers(non-durable) to a topic in activemq, but something wrong happens and one subscriber gets disconnected from the topic and never connects back again even though the protocol used is failover.
So, how can i check the status of a subscriber and if its not subscribed then connect it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try to attach an ExceptionListener to you JMS connection - it should show you once the subscriber disconnects for some reason.

Comment: by exceptionListener you mean attaching a transportListener?

Comment: I assumed you use JMS - is that right? If yes then have a look at the following code:

`// KEY - register for exception callbacks`
`connection.setExceptionListener(new ExceptionListenerImpl());`

at [Exception Listener Example](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21314744)

Comment: yes i am using jms only. I will try adding an ExceptionListener.

Comment: I found that failover protocol is used by the client, but then also its doesn't reconnect. Moreover, ExceptionListener is never called with failover protocol.

Comment: OK, I see. Have you researched the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14172547/transport-listener-and-activemq-restart

Comment: i tried adding an exceptionListener it worked fine but then i tried it with failover and it worked fine.Actually there was some problem with the code so it works fine now both the ways.
Thanks @scir.